# Ensuring grep matches from multiple files are on their own line

Tags: bash, sed, grep

Warning - Beginner in bash scripting

In a bash script I'm looking for specific data in specific lines in multiple files so I'm using a combination of grep and sed and a for loop for the array of files:

**Sample input:**
File1:
find a line with data1 and data2
find a line with data1 and data2
some other line
find a line with data1 and data2
File2:
find a line with data1 and data2
some other line
find a line with data1 and data2
find a line with data1 and data2
File3:
some other line
some other line
File4:
some other line
find a line with data1 and data2

```
for FILE in ${FILENAMES[@]}; do
   STRING=$STRING$( grep "find a line with data1 and data2" "$FILE" | sed -rn "s/(data1).*(data2).*/\1/p" )
done

echo "$STRING"
```

The problem with this method is when the for loop goes onto the next file and grep finds a line matching the pattern the match is put on the same line as the previous match, e.g.

**Sample output:**

> data1       <---- File1 
>   data1
>   data1data1  <---- File1 and File2
>   data1
>   data1
>   data1       <---- File4
>
> *File3 had no matches

To fix this I put a "\n" at the end of grep/sed line, i.e.

```
for FILE in ${FILENAMES[@]}; do
   STRING=$STRING$( grep "find a line with data1 and data2" "$FILE" | sed -rn "s/(data1).*(data2).*/\1/p" )"\n"
done

echo -e "$STRING"
```

This solves the issue of 2 matches on the same line, but it now adds an empty line when no match is found in a file or after the last match, e.g.

**Sample output:**

> data1       <---- File1
>   data1
>   data1
>   data1       <---- File1
>   data1       <---- File2
>   data1
>   data1
>                <---- File3
>   data1       <---- File4
>              <---- No more matches script finished.
>
> *File3 had no matches

So is there a way of not using "\n" but still ensuring each match in all files are in their own line or have I just taken the wrong approach with the for loop.

Hope this is clear.

Thanks
Brian

Comment: Can you show dummy input and expected output?

Comment: Sorry pfnuesel, I should of checked the formatting, have an example output in there somewhere

Comment: Hopefully the sample input and output is enough and formatted ok now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about (using your method of parsing):

```
STRING=$(
  for FILE in "${FILENAMES[@]}"; do
    grep "find a line with data1 and data2" "$FILE" | sed -rn "s/(data1).*(data2).*/\1/p"
  done
)
```

or if there are not too many files:

```
STRING=$(grep -h "find a line with data1 and data2" "${FILENAMES[@]}" | sed -rn "s/(data1).*(data2).*/\1/p")
```

==> Given your script, I am assuming `<---- File1` and such is no part of the output format..

Comment: +1 for the 2nd solution - passing _all_ filenames at once to `grep` is probably the way to go; I suggest you replace `infile2818*` with `"${FILENAMES[@]}"` (you've also switched from `sed`'s `-r` option to  `-E`, which also works, but may be confusing).

Comment: Well observed, thanks @mklement0 ! I edited my script.

Comment: Excellent, thanks mklement0 and Scrutinizer, that's exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

```
STRING="`sed -rn 's/(data1).*(data2).*/\1/p' ${FILENAMES[@]}`"

echo "$STRING"
```

why taking the loop , take directly all files to the sed action ?

Comment: Thanks for the reply NeronLeVelu, I went with the above answer as I need to filter out certain lines from each file first with grep.